How do I access the vert.x random port value in Quarkus?
I'm trying to register microservice to consul discovery service. I have not been able to do it automatically so I do it explicitly using init method with @Observes annotation. Problem arrives when I set port number to be 0 (aka random) because I'm unable to get the port, as everything I tried to do just returns 0 instead of an actual port number.
Example:
@ConfigProperty(name = "consul.host")
   String consulAddress;
   @ConfigProperty(name = "consul.port")
   int consulPort;
   Integer applicationPort;
   @ConfigProperty(name = "quarkus.application.name")
   String applicationName;
   ConsulClient consulClient;

public void init(@Observes HttpServer server, Vertx vertx) {
       applicationPort = vertx.createHttpServer().actualPort();
       System.out.println("SERVER PORT IS : " + applicationPort);

       consulClient = ConsulClient.create(vertx, new ConsulClientOptions().setHost(consulAddress).setPort(consulPort));
       consulClient.registerService(
               new ServiceOptions().setPort(applicationPort).setAddress("localhost").setName(applicationName).setId(applicationPort + ""));
   }

I have also tried HttpConfiguration.port but the result appears to be the same. Any other approach? Anything non-explicit?
!!! It appears that when live reload triggers retard the port is displayed properly. Is there any other event that I can observe that is guaranteed to happen after the port has been set?
I expected actual port number, I always receive 0.
